# Can't sent web request from .Net web api to remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, postman

I am trying to send a post request to my remote server from my .net web api project as mentioned below,

```
        [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        public string POST()
        {

           var values = new NameValueCollection();
           values["login_id"] = "XXXX";
           values["password"] = "XXXXXXXX";

           var response = client.UploadValues("http://10.17.73.60/api/login", values);

           var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);

           Console.WriteLine("Rasindu :- " + responseString);

           return responseString;
        }
```

It gives me follwing error,

> An error has occurred. 
>   The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>   
>   System.Net.WebException  at
>   System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(Uri address, String method,
>   NameValueCollection data) at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(String
>   address, NameValueCollection data) at
>   EmployeeWebApiService.Controllers.AppController.POST() in
>   C:\Users\rdealk\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\EmployeeWebApiService\EmployeeWebApiService\Controllers\AppController.cs:line
>   37 at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.b__3(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()

I could be able to send the above mentioned request using Postman successfully and also I sent the above request to a different server(Not remote server) that was also possible. Therefore I think there is a problem in .net configuration but I have no idea about it.

Below is my response to my request in postman(successfully sent)

```
{
    "User": {
        "user_id": "1",
        "name": "Administrator",
        "gender": "1",
        "birthday": "1977-10-08T04:00:00.00Z",
        "photo_exists": "false",
        "pin_exists": "false",
        "login_id": "admin",
        "password_exists": "true",
        "updated_count": "0",
        "last_modified": "0",
        "start_datetime": "2001-01-01T00:00:00.00Z",
        "expiry_datetime": "2030-12-31T23:59:00.00Z",
        "security_level": "0",
        "display_duration": "20",
        "display_count": "3",
        "permission": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Administrator",
            "description": "this is a permission for Administrator",
            "filter": {
                "UserGroup": [
                    "1"
                ],
                "DeviceGroup": [
                    "1"
                ],
                "DoorGroup": [
                    "1"
                ],
                "ElevatorGroup": [
                    "1"
                ],
                "ZoneType": [
                    "-1"
                ],
                "AccessGroup": [
                    "0"
                ],
                "GraphicMapGroup": [
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            "module": {
                "Dashboard": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                },
                "User": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                },
                "Device": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                },
                "Door": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                },
                "Elevator": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                },
                "Zone": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                },
                "AccessControl": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                },
                "Monitoring": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                },
                "TA": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                },
                "Setting": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                },
                "Video": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                },
                "Visitor": {
                    "read": "true",
                    "write": "true"
                }
            },
            "device": {
                "id": "547239744"
            },
            "user": {
                "id": "1",
                "id": "1319",
                "id": "1970",
                "id": "2345",
                "id": "2373"
            }
        },
        "inherited": "false",
        "user_group_id": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "All Users"
        },
        "disabled": "false",
        "expired": "false",
        "fingerprint_template_count": "0",
        "face_count": "0",
        "card_count": "0",
        "need_to_update_pw": "false"
    },
    "Response": {
        "code": "0",
        "link": "http://biostar.com/response.html",
        "message": "Success"
    }
}
```

Headers according to the postman request that I sent,

```
bs-session-id  -  97e09c82546d4d9a8b7c4422dc0a49d2
Content-Type   -  application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length -  1510
```

What is the best solution for this problem ?

Comment: Please show us your successful request in postman

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Thanks. And could you please a request config in postman? Such data as request data, request method, headers and so on

Comment: My headers are added

Comment: According to the Stacktrace it looks like the UploadValues method is expecting 3 parameters and you're only providing two. Are you missing the request method? ie GET, POST...
`System.Net.WebException at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(Uri address, String method, NameValueCollection data)`